# generate package.lock.json for C# projects using nuget CLI

Tags: c#, nuget, package.json

CONTEXT: we are using a SCA tool that requires a `package.lock.json` file our C#/nuget projects. I want to generate the `package.lock.json` file in our CI pipeline. I don't want to go to my devs to set the MSBuild property RestorePackagesWithLockFile in your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Is there a way to do this via CLI in the CI build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: **You should rather set it in the source code** and have alle the dependency changes also change the lock file to also review during PRs etc and actually build the software repeatably as intended by the mechanism.

This is how lock files are intended to be used to contribute to repeatable builds with stable dependencies as a supply chain sustainability and security checking measure.

That being said, there are two methods that can be used here, though **I recommend doing it in the committed source code instead**:

1. Add `-p:RestorePackagesWithLockFile=True` to each `dotnet` invocation - e.g. `dotnet restore -p:RestorePackagesWithLockFile=True my.sln`
2. Set `RestorePackagesWithLockFile` as an environment variable in your build environment or task invocations for .NET build related tasks (value `True`).